# ¿Cómo hacer una inserción de datos con subconsulta en SQL WorkBench?

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

cree una tabla bkp para respaldar una tabla original. Ahora quiero eliminar un registro de la tabla original y dejar establecida una sentencia donde inserte en la tabla original el registro que elimine, trayendo la información de la tabla bkp

supongo que la manera de realizarlo, es mediante una subconsulta. Lo estoy codeando asi pero me da error de syntaxis:

`insert into proveedores value (select * from bkp_proveedores where id_proveedor = 1);`

Comment: cuando es un subselect, no se usa values (con la S) si no que segun la db que estes usando, varia un poco la sentencia, pero suele ser insert into tabla select .....

Comment: y el pobre workbench no tiene nada que ver aca...esa es la ide que usas para conectarte a mysql, no?

Comment: @gbianchi no comprendi lo que quisiste responder... si puede ser un poco mas claro con el aporte. muchas gracias!

Comment: lee el manual ;) esta mal tu sintaxis [aca](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html)

Comment: Pues los INSERT INTO... SELECT no se hacen con una subconsulta. Y para futuras preguntas (e incluso pa esta), el error no se resume, sino que se pone dentro de tu pregunta. Y por favor, NO USES MAYÚSCULA SOSTENIDA pues, como ves, se asimila a gritos y a nadie le gustan :)